# Not able to connect with UP server APIs

Tags: jawbone

I am a developer and trying to launch https://apigee.com/jawboneapi/console/UP but getting 404 in response for last three days. Can you pls help me resolve the above issue.

thanks

Comment: Looking into this with apigee support. Will update when I discover where it went.